# Create month member groups/lists from Solspace User addon

Tags: members, stash, php, solspace-user

I am looking to create lists/groups of data from the Solspace User addon.
I am looking to list the members by their join_date from a certain group_id, for example:

July 2013 (2 members)

- member 5
- member 4

June 2013 (3 members)

- member 3
- member 2
- member 1

Would it be possible to display the number of members per group / month?

How would i go about doing this using PHP to create arrays for each grouping {join_date} should accept a format="" parameter.

Or is there a way to do this with the Stash plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is very similar to a blog archive filter. Mark Croxton has provided a very detailed example of how to pull that off.

https://gist.github.com/croxton/6219973